# new terminal at folder doesn't use default settings

Tags: macos, terminal

I have Mac OS X Mountain Lion. I program using the terminal to run my compilers. I also have the finder window open for quick access. I enabled the service "new terminal at folder", so when I right-click on a directory and select this option, it opens a new terminal window. The problem is that it doesn't open the window with my default settings (I have terminal default set to Pro settings). Is there a way to change this so it uses my default terminal settings?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the default settings for a new window/tab:

preferences > settings > [select the profile you want in the profiles side bar at left] > [click the 'default' button at the bottom of the sidebar]

[This super user post](https://superuser.com/questions/170273/make-pro-style-terminal-default-when-opening-new-tab-window) also explains this

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that *default* settings are different from *startup* settings in the terminal preferences. I changed both to Pro and it works fine now!